# Does a primary student, training in a high performance airplane, need an high performance endorsement prior to solo?

Tags: faa-regulations

A pre-solo private pilot student is training in a Cessna 182 they purchased, do they also need a high performance endorsement, as well as the solo endorsement prior to their first solo flight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  In order to solo, a student pilot must act as pilot-in-command of that aircraft, which requires a logbook endorsement for high-performance airplanes in order to do so per [§61.31(f)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.31).

> **Additional training required for operating high-performance airplanes.**
>
> (1) Except as provided in paragraph (f)(2) of this section, no person
> may act as pilot in command of a high-performance airplane (an
> airplane with an engine of more than 200 horsepower), unless the
> person has -
>
> (i) Received and logged ground and flight training from an authorized
> instructor in a high-performance airplane, or in a full flight
> simulator or flight training device that is representative of a
> high-performance airplane, and has been found proficient in the
> operation and systems of the airplane; and
>
> (ii) Received a one-time endorsement in the pilot's logbook from an
> authorized instructor who certifies the person is proficient to
> operate a high-performance airplane.

Comment: would the situation would the same for tailwheel airplane/ endorsement?

Comment: Well I don’t know…. What does §61.31 (i) state?

Comment: @quietflyer Same situation: 14 CFR 61.31(i) states ```Except as provided in paragraph (i)(2) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command of a tailwheel airplane unless that person has received and logged flight training from an authorized instructor in a tailwheel airplane and received an endorsement in the person's logbook from an authorized instructor who found the person proficient in the operation of a tailwheel airplane.``` A non-certificated pilot acts as pilot in command while flying solo, so they would need the tailwheel endorsement.